# How to pass the value of an HtmlHelper dropdown list in a javascript ajax call with onchange event?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to pass the Htmlhelper helper value of a dropdown in an ajax call

```
      @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.LanguageRouteName, (SelectList)ViewBag.LanguageEnum, new { @onchange = "submitform(event)", @class = "input-medium", @id = "languageEnum" })
```

i am trying to pass the event but i need all the values of HtmlHelper 'helper'. How do i get this value? Please Help

Answer (score 0):

$('#languageEnum').Onchange(function(){

var ddl val=$('#languageEnum').val();

$.ajax({
                    type: "GET",        //GET or POST or PUT or DELETE verb

```
                url: ajaxUrl,       // Location of the service

               data: "ddldata:ddl",         // dropdown data 

                dataType: "json",   //Expected data format from server

                success: function (json) {//On Successful service call
                    var result = json.name;
                    $("#dvAjax").html(result);
                }
```

})

});